# If write XML fails

Tags: php, xml, error-handling

Is there anyway to check if a write error has happened during a xml write? I use xml to write data but sometimes the data is corrupted/not done due to a server glitch?

I want to make sure that the xml document is written else do it again!

```
$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1"); 
$doc->formatOutput = true; 

$r = $doc->createElement( "library" ); 
$doc->appendChild( $r ); 

$b = $doc->createElement( "data" ); 

$time = $doc->createElement( "updatetime" ); 
$time->appendChild($doc->createTextNode( $timestamp )); 
$b->appendChild( $time ); 

$update = $doc->createElement( "update" ); 
$update->appendChild($doc->createTextNode(0)); 
$b->appendChild( $update ); 

$data = $doc->createElement("thestring"); 
$data->appendChild( 
$doc->createTextNode($string) 
); 
$b->appendChild( $data ); 

$r->appendChild( $b ); 

$doc->save('xml_users/'.$currplayer.'.xml');
```

Please help :-)

Comment: $doc->save shoult write the file in a single go. If you end up with half a file it is probably because the script is killed, or the disk is full. In either case it is unlikely you can solve it within the script.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `save` returns false:

Wrap everything into a function that return the DOMDocument object then call it

```
$doc = createUser($vars);
if(!$doc->save('xml_users/'.$currplayer.'.xml')){
    // run code again
    $doc = createUser($vars);
}
```

Comment: Change `if` to `while` and you're done. ;-) Keep trying. Forever.

Comment: So where "// run code again" is I should just put "createUser($vars)" ?

Comment: yes .. you can run the code again `$doc = createUser($vars);`

Comment: Should the save xml part be within the function?